# How to send confirmation e-mails using gmail smtp service for registration using devise under development mode locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have an app , it uses devise to send confirmation mails for the newly registered users , I have smtp settings under the development.rb file as

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "my_username@gmail.com",
  :password => "mygmail password"
    }
```

This is throwing me with an error like ,

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at
```

Any Ideas how to resolve this ?

Resolved using these settings ..

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => "my_username@gmail.com",
  :password             => 'my_gmail password',
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was unuable to resolve this problem with any code. After a while i logged in to gmail account and this is, what it gave me after.

```
We've detected suspicious activity on your Google Account. Please create a new password to continue using your account.

Read some tips on creating a secure password.
```

So solution to this problem is simply log into account you use for email sending and reconfirm your new password

Answer (score 1):

:authentication       => 'plain'

Comment: also u can remove :domain option

Comment: Google was blocking to send email because it detected some suspicious activity as I was trying to login from application. my gmail account ask for password chage i chaged it and now it works Thanks

Comment: The funniest thing is that error message directly pointed in that direction))

Answer (score 0):

# ActionMailer Config

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# change to false to prevent email from being sent during development
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "your_mail@gmail.com",
  password: "your_password"
}
```

After making your development.rb file like this, then if you have problem means please login to your gmail account, which is used in the development.rb file. 
Then problem will be solved.