# Sending Mail in Rails App Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, devise, actionmailer

I have Users that are able to invite others by email to a project they are working on but I keep getting the following error-

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError
```

Here is how I have mail settings configured for my production environment

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }

  #Sending email on the production side
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "example@gmail.com",
    :password => "password"
  }
```

It works in my local environment using sqlite3 as I expect but when I push to heroku it throws the above error after running heroku logs. I believe my config settings to be correct and obviously heroku uses postgresql, so what am I missing here?

Thanks for you r attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason here [How to send confirmation e-mails using gmail smtp service for registration using devise under development mode locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719192/how-to-send-confirmation-e-mails-using-gmail-smtp-service-for-registration-using)

Google had detected some "suspicious" activity on the newly created account and was blocking me from sending emails. After verifying the account I was able to send emails with the above config and switching `:domain => "heroku.com"`